# Powershell script to delete *.jpg files smaller than 6000 bytes, and delete the correspondingly named *labelled.png file?

Tags: powershell

Looking for a powershell script that can simultaneously delete *.jpg files by image size (all *.jpg less than 6000 bytes), AND simultaneously read the name of that image file and use that to search for and delete the correspondingly named *labelled.png file. There are some special characters ("[" "]" "=" " ") in the file names unfortunately, but these can be removed or replaced by "_" on beforehand, or ideally simultaneously with the same script if possible.

Here is what I use now to delete the *.jpg files less than 6000 bytes:

```
ls -Filter *.jpg -recurse -file | where {$_.Length -lt 6000} | Remove-Item -Force -recurse
```

Is there some code I can add to have the script also delete the correspondingly named *labelled.png-file if the *.jpg file is less than 6000 bytes (and first or simultaneously remove special characters)?

[Screenshot from part of the list of image-files (*.jpg) and correspondingly named (*labelled.png) mask files to be deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u15fk.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of piping directly into `Remove-Item` you can use [ForEach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-5.1) and do both delete operations there:

```bsh
ls -Filter *.jpg -recurse -file | where {$_.Length -lt 6000} | foreach {
    Remove-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Force
    Remove-Item -LiteralPath ($_.FullName -replace "\.jpg", "-labelled.png") -Force
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works brilliantly, but not with the special characters unfortunately, so have to remove them first with Bulk Rename Utility and replaced "-labelled.png" with "labelled.png" in the script. 

Is there an easy powershell script to get rid of mulitple special characters in the same run? Tried some of the ones using the special characters databases, but they didn't work, an I really just need a simple script that removes these five - brackets, equals and space ("[" "]" "=" " ").